How to change screen scale in Debian 12 using MATE desktop environment?
I recently just created a virtual machine in VMware Player with the OS. Debian 12 and the MATE desktop environment (with X11 window manager). The problem I have is regarding the resolution and scaling of the screen. The default configuration is the following:

Resolution: 1920x935
Scale: 100%

The problem is that with that resolution and scaling the windows and text look too small and it is quite difficult to read. If I change to a scale of 200% the text and windows become too large, and it is a bit uncomfortable to work that way.
The problem is that with that resolution and scaling the windows and text look too small and it is quite difficult to read. If I change to a scale of 200% the text and the windows become too large, and the windows are not shown in their entirety and I cannot interact with the buttons at the bottom of the windows, this in "normal" mode. In "Full Screen" mode I can see the buttons at the bottom of the windows, however the size is still too big, and it is a bit complicated to work that way.
Using xrandr I have tried changing the scald value to 1.5, which displays elements of a suitable size. But now I have the problem that I don't know how I can make the changes persist either by resizing the window, or by exiting and entering full screen mode and restarting the machine since the configuration is lost when doing one of the previous actions.
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1.5x1.5

How can I make the settings persistent?
